# ReactJS - How to compare/filter matching id's of two arrays and use the result in a double search feature?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to have a double search feature in my app. One search, filters books out by its title. While the other, filters books by genre. Both search filters should work together (it should filter out by title AND genre if search terms are provided).

I'm having difficulty applying the genre search filter, however.

** NOTE**: When created, each genre tag is assigned the same `id` as the book it's tagged to. This way, I can pull up all the books associated with a genre that's being search.

**Objects:**

```
book = { id: "id", title: "title", author: "author"}
genre = { id: "id", label: "label" }
```

**Parent component**

```
export default function Books() {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([])
  const [searchTitle, setSearchTitle] = useState("")
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]) 
  const [searchGenre, setSearchGenre] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://www.someapi.com/books`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(setBooks)
  }, [])

  function handleAllGenres(val){
    setGenres([...genres, val])
  }

  const filterGenres = genres.filter(genre => {
    return genre.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchGenre.toLowerCase())
  })

  const filterBooks = books.filter(book => {
    return book.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTitle.toLowerCase())
  })

  const filterBookGenres = filterBooks.filter(book => {    
    if (searchGenres.length > 0) {                 
      return filterGenres.some(genre => book.id === genre.id) 
    } else {
      return books
    }
  })

  const book = filterBookGenres.map(book => {
    return (
        <Book 
            key={book.id} 
            book={book}
            genres={genres}
            onAddGenre={handleAllGenres}
        />
    )
  })

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <SearchTitle 
        searchTitle={searchTitle} 
        onSearchTitle={setSearchTitle} 
      />
      <SearchGenre 
        searchGenre={searchGenre}
        onSearchGenre={setSearchGenre}
      />
      {book}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
export default function Book({ book, onAddGenre }) 
    const [genreTags, setGenreTags] = useState([]) 

    function handleAddGenre(e) {
        const val = {
            id: book.id,
            label: e.target.value,
        }

        if (e.key === 'Enter' && val) {
            if (genreTags.find(genre => genre.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase())) {
              return
            }
            setGenreTags([...genreTags, val])
            onAddGenre(val)
            e.target.value = ""
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="book-div">
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>Written By: {author}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="tag-div">
            <ul> 
                { genreTags && genreTags.map(tag => {
                    return <li key={uuid()}> {tag.label} </li>  
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Add a genre"
            onKeyDown={handleAddGenre} 
        />
    );
}
```

**Search Components:**

```
export default function SearchTitle({ searchTitle, onSearchTitle }) {

    return (
        <div className="search">
            <input
                id="name-input" 
                placeholder="Search by title"
                value={search} 
                onChange={e => onSearch(e.target.value)} 
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
export default function SearchGenre({ searchGenre, onSearchGenre }) {
    return (
        <div className="search">
            <input 
                id="tag-input"
                placeholder="Search by genre"
                value={searchGenre}
                onChange={e => onSearchTag(e.target.value)} 
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**UPDATE:** The search features work now, but I noticed that my tags disappear after I play around with either search features. For example, if I input a search value and filter through the books list then delete my search terms, my tags will disappear. I assume it's because the books get re-rendered?

**Is there a way to prevent this re-render or to prevent my tags from disappearing after playing around with my search feature?**

All the help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's the point of the book id to be identical to genre id? doesn't make sence to me.

Comment: A little hard to explain, but I came to this method because I couldn't think of another way to relate the genre tag back to the book it was originally assigned to on the parent component level. I'm essentially associating each genre tag to the book it's assigned to via the book id. This way when the genre filter searches for a genre tag, it can pull up all the matching genres, and subsequently correlate it back to the book(s) with the same genre tags via the matching id(s).

Comment: Each book should have a refrence to its genre, like in my example. that will allow you to filter clean and easy.

Comment: Hi, Mint. I understand how much cleaner your method works, but unfortunately I don't have the luxury of organizing it the same way. As I'm grabbing my books list from an api with set attributes (and have no access to remodel the backend or persist changes), I'm unable to give a book reference to each genre. Hence me working the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell, since I can't see what's going on inside of the onClick handlers (they're in different components).  I see one possible issue right off the bat (which is weird, considering you said genre was the issue and not title search).  In `filterBooks` you have `book => { return title.toLowerCase()...`, but it should be
`book => { return book.title.toLowerCase()...`

Also, in this code sample you're not setting `setGenres`.  Is the `genres` state empty?

**Edit**

> Is there a way to prevent this re-render or to prevent my tags from disappear after playing around with my search feature?

Yes, there's a workaround solution that we can use until we refresh the page or unmount and re-mount the `Books` component.  Objects are mutable data structures, so you could mutate them to add a new key ("tags").  These will persist, even if the `Book` object dismounts and re-mounts. We can do this from `handleAddGenre` in `Book.js` like so:

```
  function handleAddGenre(e) {
    const val = {
      id: book.id,
      label: e.target.value
    };

    if (e.key === "Enter" && val) {
      if (
        /**
         * Note that I made a small change here, 
         * adding 'labels' before the two toLowerCase methods
         */
        genreTags.find(
          (genre) => genre.label.toLowerCase() === val.label.toLowerCase()
        )
      ) {
        return;
      }
      /**
       * we mutate the book object here.  
       * This will persist until we reset the books state,
       * so searching doesn't make it disappear.
       */
      book.tags = book.tags ? [...book.tags, val] : [val];
      setGenreTags([...genreTags, val]);
      onAddGenre(val);
      e.target.value = "";
    }
  }
```

Then, we just have to change the render accordingly, since it should iterate through the books' new `tag` key to find all of the new labels

```
<ul>
  {book.tags &&
    book.tags.map((tag) => {
      return <li key={uuid()}> {tag.label} </li>;
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The `book => { return title.toLowerCase()...` bit was a typo. It got lost when copy/pasting/editing somehow, but I've updated it. My original code, indeed, did have `book.title.toLowerCase`. I've also included the other components. Please review it again and let me know if you see anything alarming. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the initial `genres` state somewhere? I pulled up the code in a codesandbbox and seem to have gotten things to work. I had to bugfix the code you put up for a moment, but all-in-all, I believe I got it to work without changing anything aside from setGenres. Check out my code below.

 https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-waterfall-xs15i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ah! Your bug fix seemed to have done it. Changing my code to `searchGenre.length > 0` worked. I  previously tried `.length > 0` too, but didn't realize I was calling it on filterGenres. Whoops! While the general filtering issue has been solved, I noticed that my tags tend to disappear after playing around with the search filters (I provided a little more detail in my update above). It happens in your sandbox too. Any idea how to fix this? Nonetheless, thank you for all the help!!! True life saver. I've been staring at this for hours.

Comment: That's awesome!  I spent quite a while debugging the sandbox lol so I'm relieved.  I just updated my answer to accommodate your new question, let me know if there's anything else. @maycheynack

Comment: Thanks for all the time you spend debugging! as for the updated answer: not sure if it's occurring on your end, but I get a typeError in your sandbox when I try to input a tag. I believe it's from `book.tags = [...book.tags, val]`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it should have been `book.tags = book.tags ? [...book.tags, val] : [val]`

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. That did the trick. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-yalow-65ikq?file=/src/App.js:0-1940)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./styles.css";

const genreList = [
  {
    id: 0,
    label: "horror",
    type: "fiction",
    desc: "these creepy crawler stories will leave you shaking in your boots!"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "action",
    type: "fiction",
    desc: "a fun, colorful adventure awaits!"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "history",
    type: "non-fiction",
    desc: "A blast from the past!"
  }
];

const bookList = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "My First Book",
    author: "Mint",
    genreId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "My Second Book",
    author: "James Bond",
    genreId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Here's the Third!",
    author: "Batman",
    genreId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "The Holy Fourth Empire",
    author: "John Snow",
    genreId: 0
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Remember Remember the Fifth of November!",
    autorh: "V",
    genreId: 0
  }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  header: {
    paddingBottom: "10px"
  },
  bookList: {
    height: "100px"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [genres, setGenres] = useState(genreList);
  const [books, setBooks] = useState(bookList);
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.header}>
        {isSelected !== null ? (
          <h4>{genres[isSelected].label} Movies</h4>
        ) : (
          <h4>All Movies</h4>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.bookList}>
        {isSelected === null
          ? books.map((book) => <p>{book.title}</p>)
          : books
              .filter((book) => book.genreId === isSelected)
              .map((book) => <p>{book.title}</p>)}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.buttons}>
        <Button onClick={() => setIsSelected(0)}>Horror</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => setIsSelected(1)}>Action</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => setIsSelected(2)}>History</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => setIsSelected(null)}>All</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```